# Writing xml file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I am new to xml. I have 10 XML files which contain some "squish report" as follows(*I am not looking for the answer just guidance on how I could approach it*):

```
<SquishReport>
<test name="mat_tst_versions">
<prolog time="2015-06-16T13:49:54+02:00"/>
<message type="FATAL" time="2015-06-16T13:50:54+02:00">
    <description><![CDATA[Execution error]]></description>
    <description type="DETAILED"><![CDATA[squishrunner exited with code 3 when executing tst_start_app]]></description>
</message>
<test name="tst_check_versions">
    <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:50:55+02:00"/>
    <message line="274" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\utilities.py" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[is 64 bit windows version: True]]></description>
    </message>            
    <message line="124" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_check_versions\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[    path exists!]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="129" type="FAIL" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_check_versions\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[expected version: 1.0.0.107]]></description>
    </message>
    <verification line="132" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_check_versions\test.py">
        <result type="PASS" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
            <description>version check test case passes!</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00"/>
</test>        
<test name="tst_scheduler_1">
    <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:51:00+02:00"/>
    <message line="62" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:00+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[count = 0]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="125" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:06+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[duration of start of C: 5132ms]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="172" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[application name = C]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="184" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[start application: C]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="213" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Scheduler Label exists]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="219" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Scheduler Counter exists]]></description>
    </message>
    <verification line="368" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
        <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:01+02:00">
            <description>different types elements</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <verification line="369" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
        <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:01+02:00">
            <description>name_list= ['Scheduler', 'NCU', 'PLCSimAdv', 'simNCK', 'MCP']</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <verification line="370" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
        <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:01+02:00">
            <description>typ_list= ['Scheduler', u'NCU', u'PLCSimAdv']</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <message line="393" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[:840evoVC.lblClockCounter_Edit = 0]]></description>
    </message>
    <verification line="411" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
        <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
            <description>scheduler counter 1. read, n=0: Scheduler= 0</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <verification line="414" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
        <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
            <description>scheduler counter 2. read, n=0: Scheduler= 0</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <message line="421" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[scheduler counter 1. read < counter 2. read, n=0: Scheduler= 0]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="484" type="ERROR" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:29+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Script Error]]></description>
        <description type="DETAILED"><![CDATA[LookupError: Object ':840evoVC.chkSchedule_CheckBox_2' not ready.]]></description>
    </message>
    <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:52:29+02:00"/>
</test>
<test name="tst_run_plc">
    <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:52:30+02:00"/>
    <verification line="45" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_run_plc\test.py">
        <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:30+02:00">
            <description>user path folder already exists!</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <message line="125" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:34+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[duration of start of 840evoVC: 4263ms]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="54" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:34+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[start ok, duration = 4263000]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="64" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:34+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[application started: 840evoVC]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="78" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:39+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[PLC Sim Advanced tmp user files are the expected files]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="263" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:45+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[all applications are closed]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="87" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:45+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[close application ok]]></description>
    </message>
    <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:52:45+02:00"/>
</test>
<test name="tst_app_resources">
    <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:52:47+02:00"/>
    <message line="65" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_app_resources\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:49+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[count:0]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="125" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:53+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[duration of start: 4176ms]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="73" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_app_resources\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:53+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[start ok, duration = 4176000]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="43" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\win32utilities.py" time="2015-06-16T13:53:00+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Application 840evovc only exists once]]></description>
    </message>            
    <message line="138" type="ERROR" file="C:\test\mat_tst_\tst_app_resources\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:53:30+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Script Error]]></description>
        <description type="DETAILED"><![CDATA[LookupError: Object ':chkSchedule_CheckBox_2' not ready.
            Called from:
        C:\test\mat_tst\tst_app_resources\test.py: 82]]></description>
    </message>
    <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:53:30+02:00"/>
</test>
<test name="tst_reset">
    <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:53:32+02:00"/>   
    <message line="260" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Process exited.]]></description>          
    </message>
    <message line="263" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[all applications are closed]]></description>
    </message>
    <message line="284" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_reset\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[application closed]]></description>
    </message>
    <verification line="287" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_reset\test.py">
        <result type="PASS" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
            <description>tst_reset_1 ok</description>
            <description type="DETAILED"></description>
        </result>
    </verification>
    <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00"/>
</test>
<epilog time="2015-06-16T13:56:13+02:00"/>
</test> 
</SquishReport>
```

Now I want to create another XML file which contains a summary of the XML files. What I need to have in new XML file just only the `</test>
</SquishReport>` of each file and then a line link this

```
<result state= "Passed" href="link to the file"*.xml />
```

`"Passed"` if `<result type="PASS"` otherwise `"NOT Passed"`.

In total what I expect in new XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<summary>
  <testcase name="name of testcase1">
     <result state= "Passed" href="link to file1"*.xml /> (for the first file)
     <result state= "Passed" href="link to file2"*.xml /> (for the second file)
     ......
  <testcase/>
  <testcase name="name of testcase2">
     <result state= "Passed" href="link to file1"*.xml /> (for the first file)
     <result state= "Passed" href="link to file2"*.xml /> (for the second file)
     ......
  <testcase/>
  ....
  <testcase name="name of testcasen">
     <result state= "Passed" href="link to file1"*.xml /> (for the first file)
     <result state= "Passed" href="link to file2"*.xml /> (for the second file)
     ......
  <testcase/>
<summary/>
```

**Edit:** Here is what I have so far:

```
  sub FileCount
{
chdir( $dir ) or die "Couldn't go inside $dir directory, $!";
opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$0: $dir: $!\n";
while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    # We only want files
     next unless (-f "$dir/$file");
    # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .xml
     next unless ($file =~ m/$suff$/);

     my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

    # Iterate the entries                           
     for my $test ($xml->findnodes('/SquishReport/test/test')) {
        my $name_test = $test->findvalue('@name');  

        # looks for if the results is OK or not
        for my $result ($test->findnodes('./verification/result')) {
            my $type_result = $result->findvalue('@type');
            ### -----------------------------------------------------------------------
             my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');
             my $root = $doc->createElement("summary");
             $root->setAttribute('testcase_name'=> "$name_test");

             for my $case_name (keys %tags) {
                 my $tag = $doc->createElement($case_name);
                 my $value = $tags{$case_name};
                 $tag->appendTextNode($value);
                 $root->appendChild($tag);
             }

            $doc->setDocumentElement($root);
            ### -----------------------------------------------------------------------
            print "$type_result = $value_result \n";
            if (($type_result eq "WARNING") || ($type_result eq "FAIL") || ($type_result eq "ERROR") || ($type_result eq "FATAL")){
                $value_result = "OK";
                print "***********  $name_test is not OK *********** \n\n "; 
            }
            else{
                $value_result = "NOT_OK";
                print "***********  $name_test is OK *********** \n\n ";
            }
        }
        print "\n";
     }
    #}
     print "$file\n";       
     $count = $count + 1;
}
closedir($dh);  

my $filename = 'report.xml';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh $doc->toString();
close $fh;
```

Comment: [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0122/LibXML.pod)

Comment: What's the issue/output?

Comment: You're creating more summary files than original files. Why?

Comment: @reinierpost I want to creat only one file including all data needed. These data are taken from original files.

Comment: @Pradeep I have not the desired output. this is why I have not written my output here.

Comment: The overall logic can be cleaned up a little, it becomes hard to understand what happens. I think it would be better to open the output file once, at the top, write a subroutine that takes a filename and adds that file's contribution to the output, and call that subroutine for each input file. The general approach seems fine. Another possible approach is to use XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it like this:

- Use `XML::Twig` (because I like it).
- Create a "parent" XML document
- iterate each XML file and use the `cut` and `paste` methods in `XML::Twig` to transfer the content across (and prune it if necessary). I'm pretty sure `XML::LibXML`  can do this too, if you prefer it.
- Print the "parent" doc.

Something a little like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $new_xml = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented_a' );
$new_xml->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('summary') );
$new_xml->set_xml_version('1.0');
$new_xml->set_encoding('utf-8');

my $input_processor = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('sample_squish.xml');
foreach my $result ( $input_processor->findnodes('//result') ) {
    $result->cut;
    $result->paste( $new_xml->root );
}

open( my $output, '>', 'summary.xml' ) or die $!;
print {$output} $new_xml->sprint;
close($output);
```

You'll need to:

- iterate your files (I've only got one sample) with a `foreach`/`glob`
- select the `findnodes` expression. The above only gathers `result` elements, but I think you want more than that. Remember - you can either `findnodes` again, or use `children` to act on ... child nodes, or `parent` to act on the parent node. (e.g. `$result -> parent -> att('file')`)
- modify the elements.
- paste them into the original document.

I couldn't quite figure out how your testcases/names mapped from source to summary - so it may also be useful to know you can add in a *new* node if you want:

```
my $testcase = $new_xml -> root -> insert_new_elt('testcase', { name => "name_of_the_test" }); 
$testcase ->set_att('some_other_att', 42);
$result->cut;
$result->paste( $testcase );
```

This'll insert the `$result` element from one file, into the newly created `testcase` element in the new document.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a document per file per test. You need to hoist the document creation (as well as the root creation etc.) out of the loop.

The XPATH /SquishReport/test/test looks as if it should be /SquishReport/test

And, at some point you will need to do something with $doc (like writing to a file)

Comment: Thanks. Oh, I have forgotten to write it as well here. I did now.